# Retrieve the Cloud dataflow custom counters from Grafana using Google Cloud Monitoring datasource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, monitoring, grafana, google-cloud-stackdriver

Am trying to read the custom counters from our Cloud Dataflow jobs into Grafana using Google Cloud Monitoring datasource but unable to do that (am able to get these from Stackdriver monitoring). Am able to get the job level metrics for dataflows but not the custom counters.

Can anyone please help or guide me on how to retrieve the custom counters from Garafana.